# Conocer la memoria ram máxima consumida en una ejecución (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Me preguntaba si hay alguna forma de conocer con un comando el uso de memoria de un proceso durante su tiempo de ejecución.

Me explico, si ejecuto el script exec.sh, hay algún comando que pueda recoger el uso de memoria de este y que se dé al acabar la ejecución (terminal o log). Esto podría ser memoria máxima, media y mínima.

Conozco como conocer la memoria del servidor además del porcentaje de un proceso (ps).

Muchas gracias

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿qué operaciones haces para que el uso de memoria de un script de bash sea significativo?

Comment: Te sirven `htop`, `top`, o `atop`?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón ejecuto software bioinformático y también scripts creado por mi. Muchas veces con datos masivos.

@Cuauhtli supongo que `atop` podría ayudarme a trackear el uso de manera manual, aún así, estaría interesado en una solución automática.

Comment: @agerre, ¿no estarás más interesado en el uso de memoria de *procesos hijos* del proceso bash? Si es así, tal vez deberías plantear mejor la pregunta.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón, supongo que podría darse el caso de que me llegara a interesar un proceso hijo del proceso principal. En tal caso, ¿cómo debería enfocar la pregunta?. Disculpa mi torpeza si he confundido términos. Gracias

Answer (score -1):

Tu necesidad es algo especifica. Hay varios programas que devuelven informes o lecturas a timepo real, pero para obtener un valor `min,max,avg` hay que hacer `accounting` y/o [`profiling`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lisis_de_rendimiento_de_software) si te intersa tambien la branca de programacion.

Te propongo 2 soluciones, una manual y otra automatica.

### ATOP

Programa que muestra informes de todos los procesos y mucha información hacia ellos. La diferencia con `htop` o `top` es que puede crear registros con intervalos, o hasta incluso dejarlo siempre encendido para que diariamente haga registros a lo `demoneo` del sistema.

En tu caso, puedes abrir una instacia de atop creando un log, y cuando tengas tiempo lo analizas en el tiempo manualmente.

#### Inconvenientes :

- espacio en el disco
- guarda todos los procesos / tareas

### pidstat

- Puedes mostrar solo un proceso.
- Puedes arrancarlo junto a un programa, y mostrar un `average` de los datos al final de la ejecucion : opcion `-e program`

ejemplo con informe de memoria `-r`

```
➜  networkc pidstat -r -p 731422 1 
Linux 5.8.0-38-generic (gil-NUC10i7FNH)     24/1/21     _x86_64_    (12 CPU)

10:13:24      UID       PID  minflt/s  majflt/s     VSZ     RSS   %MEM  Command
10:13:25     1000    731422      0,00      0,00 5458576  760516   2,33  FreeCAD
10:13:26     1000    731422      0,00      0,00 5458576  760516   2,33  FreeCAD
10:13:27     1000    731422      0,00      0,00 5458576  760516   2,33  FreeCAD
10:13:28     1000    731422      0,00      0,00 5458576  760516   2,33  FreeCAD
10:13:29     1000    731422      0,00      0,00 5458576  760516   2,33  FreeCAD
10:13:30     1000    731422      0,00      0,00 5458576  760516   2,33  FreeCAD
10:13:31     1000    731422      0,00      0,00 5458576  760516   2,33  FreeCAD
10:13:32     1000    731422      0,00      0,00 5458576  760516   2,33  FreeCAD
10:13:33     1000    731422      0,00      0,00 5458576  760516   2,33  FreeCAD
Average:     1000    731422      0,00      0,00 5458576  760516   2,33  FreeCAD
```

Comment: No es exactamente lo que buscaba pero puedo intentar `pidstat`, de hecho, no lo conocía. Quizás estoy preguntando por algo no tan sencillo como esperaba. Gracias por la explicación.